# Cant duplicate products in magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, e-commerce

my ideas where to search for the error are decreasing any minute.

If i try to duplicate products from the admin panel i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'attribute_id' in 'where clause'
```

In the exception.log i find:

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'attribute_id' in 'where clause'' in /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#4 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#5 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(661): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('DELETE FROM `ca...')
#6 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(236): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->delete('catalog_product...', Array)
#7 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Action.php(78): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->_saveAttributeValue(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute), '0000000003636')
#8 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Action.php(72): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Action->updateAttributes(Array, Array, 0)
#9 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/community/MDN/BarcodeLabel/Helper/Generation.php(36): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action->updateAttributes(Array, Array, 0)
#10 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/community/MDN/BarcodeLabel/Model/Observer.php(50): MDN_BarcodeLabel_Helper_Generation->storeBarcode('363')
#11 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): MDN_BarcodeLabel_Model_Observer->model_save_after(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(MDN_BarcodeLabel_Model_Observer), 'model_save_afte...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('model_save_afte...', Array)
#14 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(465): Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_afte...', Array)
#15 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(548): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#16 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/community/MDN/AdvancedStock/Model/Catalog/Product.php(23): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->_afterSave()
#17 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): MDN_AdvancedStock_Model_Catalog_Product->_afterSave()
#18 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(1142): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#19 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(767): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->duplicate()
#20 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->duplicateAction()
#21 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('duplicate')
#22 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}
```

I checked the database and the field attribute_id is there, if i try to just remove the association from the code it says there is no field shop_id and so on. They all do exist.

It seems to have something todo with the zend framework, as tablename and attributes seem correct as far as i can tell.

Any ideas how this can happen?

Comment: It happens because it cannot find the column. Machines dont think, its not lying to you, give us more info.

Comment: if you disable MDN/BarcodeLabel does it change something ? else it can be advancedstock as well

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /data/webs/128/12312/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php on line 135 ~ is what i get if i try to disable MDN. @MrJack i have no idea what information would help actually.

Comment: Your code, your query, basically what is making it fail. All the error tells us is that it cant find it. Are you pointing to the correct database at least?

Comment: @ Chris i was able to disable those modules but it didnt change anything. @MrJack It is a running, live, shop system with several orders a day. I assume the database is correct. And there is no code, or query, basically we are talking about the core functionality that somehow doesnt work as expected. I will update a few more lines code into my question now anyway. Edit// just realized there is nothing i could add from source. It is all orginal zend/magento code as far as i can tell.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in the code. The fact ebay owns it doesnt mean it cannot possibly have a bug. If you can't find a database column, its not the machine thinking it will play a trick on you. There is a reason. Maybe you dont point to correct DB, maybe db user doesnt have access to a specific table. Is your version up to date?

Comment: I think the notice you get comes from the cache and that the error is linked with this module as it is the last one called in the stack trace you provide. when we speak of disabling it means to change the true into false in local/module/according.xml or just in admin ?

Comment: only the admin. and also i did not clear the cache. Will try disabling it manually now. edit:// There is no local dir

Comment: oh yeah. yes it worked. Found the directory, now i can dig into the modules to debug and dont have to debug the whole shop and all its frameworks. Thanks!